# PHP Routing System - own MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller, routes

I am trying to develop my own MVC and i got to the point where a routing system is due.

I have used some examples from the internet and partially it works fine. Evan so, i think something is wrong and i will detail it right bellow.

My MVC has a frontend and a backend. The first question is : Do i need to load the same routing system for the frontend and the backend? Or do i need to have different routing systems? How would you choose?

In the frontend, whenever i am using the main menu to navigate i can go to home or contact page and the pages are displaying corectlly - and the browser url - looks fine : localhost/home or localhost/contact (without the php extension - which is the desired behaviour.)

In the backend section of my website - reaching it by using localhost/admin - of course the routing system from my front-end section has some rules for the admin, so when i am reaching the admin section the browser url is fine - showing http://localhost/admin/ and displays some login form. The Login Form uses post to send info to another page- login.php which runs the login system, and if successfull requires a page named home.php. The problem is after the successfull login - the browser url is http://localhost/admin/login.php !!! which IS NOT the desired behaviour because i am expecting in fact localhost/admin/home (without the php extension) . i have tried with a different routing system for the backend - but for some reason it's not taken in consideration and i have also tried to include the routing system after the succesfull login. I cannot find a good solution. I am surely missing something and i do not know why so please help me. This is how my routing system is  looking.

```
<?php
    // Include router class
    include('Route.php');

// Add base route (startpage)
    Route::add('/',function(){
        require 'pages/home.php';
    });

// Simple test route that simulates static html file
    Route::add('/contact',function(){
        require 'pages/contact.php';
    });

// Post route example
    Route::add('/contact-form',function(){
        echo '<form method="post"><input type="text" name="test" /><input type="submit" value="send" /></form>';
    },'get');

// Post route example
    Route::add('/contact-form',function(){
        echo 'Hey! The form has been sent:<br/>';
        print_r($_POST);
    },'post');

// Accept only numbers as parameter. Other characters will result in a 404 error
    Route::add('/foo/([0-9]*)/bar',function($var1){
        echo $var1.' is a great number!';
    });
    
    Route::run('/');
```

My router Class:

```
class Router
    {
        /**
         * The request we're working with.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        public $request;
        
        /**
         * The $routes array will contain our URI's and callbacks.
         * @var array
         */
        public $routes = [];
        
        /**
         * For this example, the constructor will be responsible
         * for parsing the request.
         *
         * @param array $request
         */
        public function __construct(array $request)
        {
            /**
             * This is a very (VERY) simple example of parsing
             * the request. We use the $_SERVER superglobal to
             * grab the URI.
             */
            $this->request = basename($request['REQUEST_URI']);
        }
        
        /**
         * Add a route and callback to our $routes array.
         *
         * @param string   $uri
         * @param Callable $fn
         */
        public function addRoute(string $uri, \Closure $fn) : void
        {
            $this->routes[$uri] = $fn;
        }
        
        /**
         * Determine is the requested route exists in our
         * routes array.
         *
         * @param  string  $uri
         * @return boolean
         */
        public function hasRoute(string $uri) : bool
        {
            return array_key_exists($uri, $this->routes);
        }
        
        /**
         * Run the router.
         *
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function run()
        {
            if($this->hasRoute($this->request)) {
                $this->routes[$this->request]->call($this);
            }
        }
    }
```

and my successfull login statement which redirect to home :

```
    
        if ($login) {
            require './pages/home.php';
        } else {
            echo 'ERROR';
        }
```

my htaccess from the admin section folder :

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

FallbackResource /index.php

# enable apache rewrite engine
RewriteEngine on

# set your rewrite base
# Edit this in your init method too if you script lives in a subfolder
RewriteBase /admin

# Deliver the folder or file directly if it exists on the server
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Push every request to index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA]
```

Comment: Hmm, this Router is very basic and might have other problems. I recommend you to check out this tutorial: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=6ERdu4k62wI and then start building your own MVC framework.

Comment: I am confused: usually the "frontend" in a web application refers to _the client side logic_ , so javascript, which the "backend" refers to the logic on the server side, so the php part of the application ...

Comment: mybe it's not very clear, but i will rephrase. My MVC has a frontend where i will display everything for the user using HTML CSS, JQUERY and a backend in PHP where i will make all the logic, and an admin, where the user can enter and set some things up which also have a frontend where i display the admin stuff to the user and a backend in PHP where i will make all the logic..

Comment: I'd suggest to develop an MVC-based application for the _"frontend"_ area and a separate MVC-based application for the _"backend"_ area. Each application should have its own set of components (routing, error handling, controllers, views, domain model-specific components, etc).

Comment: Creating an MVC-based application from scratch is not about creating all needed libraries (like router, dependency injection container, template engine, etc) from scratch, by yourself - unless you want to spend years doing this, with a very good reason. It is "just" about designing and developing an application (by your own business rules), which follows the [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) principle.

Comment: This means: concentrate yourself on dividing your application into the proper M, V, and C components, and on correctly creating the corresponding classes. Of course, for each of your MVC-based applications you'll need a router, a dependency injection container, a template engine, etc. Just use the libraries created by other people for that. For example, use [FastRoute](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute) - which is one of the best ones - as the router component of your application(s). And [PHP-DI](https://php-di.org/) as the DI container.

Comment: A note: A router should not invoke a route. It should just match the request components (the HTTP method and the URI path) to the components of each route (the list of HTTP methods and the pattern) in a collection of routes and return the matched route, in order to further be processed by other components (like a route invoker, for example). So, a router should not contain a method similar to your `Router::run()` method. This should be the job of another component, like a route invoker, for example. Here is one: [PHP-DI/Invoker](https://github.com/PHP-DI/Invoker).